# How to test OpenCV samples on Android Java on MacOS

Tags: java, android, macos, android-studio, opencv

I’ve been trying to get this to work for weeks on and off. Does anyone know how to take OpenCV 4.5.1, load it into Android Studio using Java bindings, build the OpenCV samples and then run in simulator? All on MacOS.

There’s a lot out there but I guess I haven’t came across the secret sauce, yet.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can build all this stuff, bundle it to arm `.so` with `llvm` (android ndk) and then do loadlibrary in code that goes to studio .